# Couchbase: querying multiple atomic counter documents with view

Tags: c#, couchbase

I have many documents in my Couchbase bucket. Some of these documents used as counters with atomic operations so they store just one number. All of these counter documents have common prefix in key ('**SomePrefix_**', for example). How can I access all these "prefixed" documents? They are doesn't appear in the views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was in using `startsWith` function.
Use `indexOf(...) === 0` to define if the key starts with substring.

Answer (score 0):

Counters are not excluding from view results by default. Probably you are doing so unintentionally in your mapper. Here, for example, mapper which takes into account the counters.

```
function (doc, meta) {
  if (meta.type == 'base64') {
    emit(meta.id, {counter: decodeBase64(doc)});
  } else {
    emit(meta.id, doc);
  }
}
```

I guess that you are trying to work with `doc` as JSON object, which cause the mapper to filter out counters.

Comment: After couple of releases (currently using server 3.0.2) these counter documents appeared in view results! Nothing changed in map/reduce :-) It's a kind of magic.

Comment: But today we have another problem. Counter docs base64 encoded. `decodeBase64` results in array of char codes. For example, instead of `9` we have `[ 59 ]` in value column.